# I have a Signature from Digital Certificate . But how to convert it to Digital Signature and append it to a pdf in java

Tags: digital-signature, digital-certificate

I have a String with signature data extracted from Digital Signature using 
document.JSignApplet.sign().
Now I would like to use this string to get the details of the certificate user and generate a Digital signature of him with it in a pdf file.
Is this possible if yes how and if not why?

Comment: What is `JSignApplet`?

Comment: JSignApplet is the Applet class in signapplet.jar which is used to read the certificate details from the browser.

Comment: Probably the [JSignApplet.java](https://code.google.com/p/vjsign/source/browse/trunk/JSign/src/jsign/applet/JSignApplet.java?r=8) from [vjsign](https://code.google.com/p/vjsign/)?

Comment: That is what I assume your `JSignApplet` is from. To check what is possible using your applet one has to know it. So, is your applet from there? If not, from where is it?